# how display text depending on an observable value with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

i am having some issue displaying a text based on the value of a select Tag
 here is how my viewModel looks like :

```
viewmodel ={
    myValues: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    quantityWanted: ko.observable("2")
}
```

and here is my View

```
<select data-bind="options: myValues, value: quantityWanted"></select>
```

now i want to display this span only when the selected value egual 1 something like this

```
<span data-bind="visible: viewmodel.quantityWanted == 1">is on</span>
```

i tried

```
viewmodel.quantitywanted.subscribe(function(){});
```

but it works only when i am on the same view. how can i change the visibility depending on the select value?

can anyone help me on this thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing expressions in your `data-bind` attribute you'll need to add `()` for any observables.

```
<span data-bind="visible: quantityWanted() == 1">is on</span>
```

Should work.

Comment: Try it without `viewmodel`. (See my edit.) Also please be more specific with *how* it's not working. Is it always displayed? Always hidden? Are there any console errors?

Comment: an other question how do you deal with strings? let say i use word in myValues this wont work data-bind="visible: quantityWanted() != one"

Comment: `quantityWanted() == 1` works in this case because you are doing a loose comparison with `==` comparing the integer `1` to the the string `'1'`

Comment: data-bind="visible: quantityWanted() != 'one'" works fine :-)